# How can I secure a shed with a skid foundation in a windy location?

Tags: foundation, shed, wind

I'm planning to install an 8'x8' composite storage shed in my backyard on a 4x4 skid foundation. However, my house is located in a very windy location. In the past 4 years, I've had my wooden privacy fence blown down twice. One of the times the wind was strong enough (just brushed by the edge of an EF4) to pull the concrete footings of the fence completely out of the ground.

I'd like to secure it as much as practical, but only to the point of which the shed itself will be able to endure. What I mean by that is that I don't care if the hold-downs fail if the shed is already destroyed.

So what's the best method to use?

- Just set the foundation on concrete blocks and rely on the weight of the contents to hold it down
- Drive some sort of ground screw next to the outer skid corners and use an eyebolt in the skids to attach with carabiners or wires.
- Pour concrete piers with 4x4 stumps sticking out of them and use carriage bolts through the skids and stumps.
- Something else I'm not thinking of?

I'd rather not have to pour concrete unless absolutely necessary. I've never done it before, and it seems like a hassle. If it's not as bad as I think it sounds, I'm open to being convinced otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at some mobile home anchoring systems you might be able to adapt something to a smaller scale. They appear similar to the screw in the earth anchors used for dog run tie outs albeit on a larger scale. I would screw in three dog anchors on each side and use a ratcheting cargo strap (available at any auto parts store) to cinch it down. It may take two straps hooked together to get enough length to go over the roof.

Comment: Your answer got me on the right track. I found these [earth anchors](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B000N50L4C?pc_redir=1397324745&robot_redir=1) specifically designed for sheds that I think I'm going to end up using.